# Weird Popup Box While Importing (Restoring) Firefox Bookmarks in Ubuntu Studio - What is It and Why Can't I Close It?

Tags: firefox, 22.04, bookmarks

I imported Firefox bookmarks from my Kubuntu install into my Ubuntu Studio install and got a popup box I’ve never seen before and cannot close because it only has options to maximize and minimize (i.e. no “x” to close it). Actually, it’s several of the same popup box. I don't know what it is and I also don’t know what process it is so that I can kill it.

The message says, “Open with…” followed by “Select an application to open x-scheme-handler/fake-favicon-uri. More applications are available in Discover.” Then there is a box that would be where applications are listed, but it’s empty.

I have no idea what this is all about and, as I said, I can’t close the windows, only minimize them. I’ve successfully imported bookmarks into Firefox in Kubuntu and other distros before without this issue. However, whereas before I used the *import* function, which uses an html file, this time I opted to *restore* the bookmarks. (This is because I couldn't actually import the .json file Firefox exported them to. Restore was the only option for this file type.)

Any thoughts? Should I be concerned?

Btw, the bookmarks did successfully import. I just can't get rid of these weird windows.

I’m running Firefox 104.0.1 on Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

[image: weird Firefox popup]

Comment: I rebooted to get rid of those popups. I then deleted all the "restored" bookmarks, re-exporting them from Kubuntu as HTML and importing them in Ubuntu - the normal way, I guess you could say - because Firefox wasn't finding them when I typed in the search bar. My post seems almost like a non-question at this point. I was thinking of deleting it but maybe I'll keep it up in case a) anyone has anything to say about that non-closable window I described or b) someone else is foolish enough to try dealing with bookmarks the way I did and goes looking for answers.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/10xhx4h/what_is_this_fakefaviconuri_popup_that_keeps/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: If you look at "File associations", and search for "uri", is Firefox assiciated?

Comment: I'm not sure about the file associations. This was a few months ago. I had to reboot to make it all go away, because there was no way to close/dismiss the window and I didn't know what process to kill. I think, in my case, I had the issue was because I tried to "restore" my bookmarks from a file created by another distro. The previous distro used normal Firefox and the new one used the Snap package. I should have been importing it rather than restoring. Of course, this doesn't explain the strange popup or why it couldn't be closed, but I think it's the reason I had it.